# Removing double quotes in the beginning and end of the String to use in a DB query

Tags: groovy

I have a string  `creationDate = "add_months(sysdate,-1)"`. I have to remove the double quotes so I can use the value in a DB query. I have tried `replace` and `replaceAll` and I have had no luck. My code is in groovy

Comment: Why do you think your string contains double quatas?

Comment: I removed the java tag because it is not relative to the question

Comment: Give wide context, hard to understand. Bigger fragment of code. Personally I think @Jeff Scott Brown give good answer, but in different understanding of context

Answer (score 0):

If the input string is `"add_months(sysdate,-1)"` and those double quotes really are in the string then you can remove the double quotes a number of ways.  One is using a range inside of the subscript operator as shown below:

```
groovy:000> input = '"add_months(sysdate,-1)"'
===> "add_months(sysdate,-1)"
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> input
===> "add_months(sysdate,-1)"
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> result = input[1..-2]
===> add_months(sysdate,-1)
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> input
===> "add_months(sysdate,-1)"
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> result
===> add_months(sysdate,-1)
```

Note that `input[1..-2]` evaluates to a string that begins with the second character and ends with the second to the last character.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Personally I understand question in (very) different way - but agree, You write answer in good style

Comment: @JacekCz "Personally I understand question in (very) different way" - I took "I have to remove the double quotes..." to mean he wanted to know how to remove the leading and trailing `"` from the string `"add_months(sysdate,-1)"`.

Comment: My understanding is: over-protection against GString substitution (which not occur). Maybe both of us understand wrong :) Question is not precise

Comment: @JacekCz "My understanding is: over-protection against GString substitution..." - `GString` is never mentioned in the question and there is no example of a `GString` in the question.  There is a double quoted but he indicates the quotes are actually in the string which doesn't make it a `GString`.  If you hardcode a `String` literal in your source code like `def foo = "some double quoted string"`, the compiler recognizes there are no tokens and creates a `String`, not a `GString`.  I don't think `GString` is relevant.  If it is, the question is poorly worded.

Comment: @JacekCz See https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/815620660a7a4c2d310b58b593cefc08 for clarification of what I mentioned above.

Comment: I know. Discussion is "what asker mean". Thread should be closed because lack of interest by primary asker. Look in question at left side `creationdate = ...` this is puzzle I have not resolved